# Task allocation with constraints using Python

Tags: python, constraints, allocation

I am working on a project where I need to allocate some tasks (processes) in hosts (computers).
My problem is similar to the cloud balancing tutorial in [this](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.0.1.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#quickStart) page.
I have the following classes:

```
Host(name, cpu=None, mem=None, taskCap=None, encrypt=None, latClass=None, loc=None)
```

`cpu`, `mem`, `taskCap` are the `Host's` capacities in CPU power, memory power and number of tasks respectively.

```
Task(name, cpuReq=None, memReq=None, execTime=None, utility=None, encrypted=None)
```

`cpuReq`, `memReq` are the `Task's` requirements in CPU and memory respectively.

I also have 2 dictionaries.
One is about the host's latency and one about the tasks's requirements on latency

For example we have 4 hosts `(h1 .. h4)` and six tasks `(t1 .. t6)`

```
h_lat_dir = {2: [(h1, h2), (h4, h4)], 3: [(h1, h1), (h1, h4)], 6: [(h2, h2)], 5: [(h1, h3), (h2, h3), (h3, h3)]}
```

The `h_lat_dir` tells us that between hosts `h1` and `h2` the latency is 2, between `h1` and `h4` is 3 and so forth.

Similarly,

```
t_lat_dir = {3: [(t1, t2)], 4: [(t1, t3), (t1, t4), (t1, t5)], 5: [(t2, t3)]}
```

where tasks `t1` and `t2` require to be mapped on hosts whose latency is less than or equal to 3.

I should also check if tasks "fit" in the hosts.
For example `t1` and `t2` can be mapped on `h1` and `h2`, respectively, only if the `cpu`, `mem` and `taskCap` of `h1` and `h2` are more than `t1`'s and `t2`'s requirements.

I am thinking to create 2 graphs to solve this problem

```
hostgraph = {'h2': {'h2': 6, 'h3': 5}, 'h3': {'h3': 5}, 'h1': {'h2': 2, 'h3': 5, 'h1': 3}}
[('b', 4), ('c', 3), ('a', 1)]
```

and

```
taskgraph = {'t2': {'t3': 5}, 't1': {'t4': 4, 't5': 4, 't2': 3, 't3': 4}}
```

in each graph the keys represent the vertices and the values are dictionaries with keys
the vertices conected to them and values the latencies.

My approach to the problem is to take each task (starting with the one with the most "connections") and do a depth first search on the host graph, checking the constraints.
I am thinking I should start with a dictionary like 
`Mappings = {t1:False, t2:False....}` and if I find hosts for the tasks to change their values to the host.

=> `Mappings = {t1:h1, t2:h2...}`

The solution should have the most tasks mapped (it is ok if some tasks are not mapped).

So, my questions:
 1. Do you think there is a better or an existing solution/approach to my problem?
 2. How do you recommend to keep track of the best solution? 
I am thinking a dictionary `{#oftasksmapped: Mappings0, #oftasksmapped: Mappings2...}` where the solution is the Mappings with the highest number of tasks mapped.

Comment: Typically the issues you see with this type of problem have more to do with coordination and dealing with failures rather than the data structures in your code.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: I think, actually, that's what I'm asking *you* to do with your question. You're asking for something "better" without specifying what "better" might even mean.

Comment: I meant a more optimal solution but, any solution or suggestion is welcome. I am actually stuck.